# Push each forEach object into a scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope that contains multiple objects. I only want to display the objects that have the `department: Directing` value.

So I wrote a `forEach` that checks if the value of `department` is equal to the string `Directing`.

```
var directed = $scope.moviesFromActorResponse.credits.crew
angular.forEach(directed, function(directed) {
    if (directed.department == 'Directing') {
        console.log(directed)
    }
});
```

This works fine, the console log returns only the objects that match the directing string. But how do I store each object from the `forEach` into one `$scope` so I can use it in my `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$scope.myList=directed.filter(function(x){ return x.department == 'Directing'; });
```

then display `$scope.myList` from `ng-repeat`

Comment: Again you re spot on. This is just javascript though right? Because it doesn't make a lot of sence to me ;).

Comment: yap this is pure javascript :)

Comment: Yea something I should definitly put more effort in. But it's so hard since jQuery, and now angular was so much more fun/easy to learn. Anyway, thanks for the quick response and help!

Comment: Nothing is hard or impossible if you have passion to do it , mate :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to skin the cat.

First, the angular.forEach example shows that it takes three arguments: an array or object, an iterator, and an object referred to by `this` within the iterator. in the example the third parameter is an empty array and it pushes results into it. Its advantage over the Javascript forEach is handling hasOwnProperty and undefined values. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

`var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
    var log = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
      this.push(key + ': ' + value);
    }, log);
    expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);`

The Javascript .filter only works with arrays.

This plunk shows the use of the $filter service in Javascript and HTML

http://plnkr.co/edit/7FlTPg?p=info

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($filter) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.search = {
      'dept': 'directing'
    };
    vm.crew = [{
      'name': 'fred',
      'dept': 'camera'
    }, {
      'name': 'ethel',
      'dept': 'camera'
    }, {
      'name': 'lucy',
      'dept': 'camera'
    }, {
      'name': 'ricky',
      'dept': 'directing'
    }];
    vm.directors = $filter('filter')(vm.crew, vm.search, true);
  })
```

.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as ct'>
    <h1>Filter/forEach example</h1>
    <h2>No filter</h2>
    <p ng-repeat='member in ct.crew'>{{member}}</p>
    <h2>filter in ng-repeat</h2>
     <p ng-repeat='member in ct.crew|filter:ct.search'>{{member}}</p>
         <h2>Using $filter in Javascript</h2>
    <p ng-repeat='member in ct.directors'>{{member}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```